# How can I display more elements in a react native View?

Tags: ios, react-native, view, render, element

I would like to show on the homepage of my react native app , a view that in turn shows a text element and an icon, then below these 2 I would like to show the amazon logo. I tried but it only shows me the logo.

```
export default class Header extends Component {
render() {
return (
  <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
    <Text style={styles.Title}>Acquista!</Text>
    <Ionicons name="ios-contact" size={42} color='red' style={{ marginTop: 
65, marginLeft: 210 }} />
  </View> ,
  <Logo></Logo>

);
}
}
class Logo extends Component {
render() {
return (
  <View>
    <Image
      style={{ height: 200, width: 200, marginTop: 150 }}
      source={require('./assets/images/amazon.jpg')}
    />

  </View>
);
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Note that you can use a tool such as [prettier](https://prettier.io/playground/) to format your code before including it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap everything into a `View`

```js
return (
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
      <Text style={styles.Title}>Acquista!</Text>
      <Ionicons name="ios-contact" size={42} color='red' style={{ marginTop: 65, marginLeft: 210 }} />
    </View>
    <Logo />
  </View>
)
```

Comment: Oh yes...I tried,but it render me only the logo and not the icon or the title

Comment: @MattiaCannavò I've updated my code to include `flex: 1` on the wrapper `View`, based on this snack https://snack.expo.io/S1tByrfq4